# Why a segmentation fault in the main function, but not in an external one?

Tags: c

The below code, when used, reads the input path, reads the text in the file at that path, and returns one string containing all the content from that file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* readFile(char *path) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255];

    char *str;

    fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if(fp) {
        while(fgets(buff, 255, fp)) {
            strcat(str, buff);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return str;
}
```

This next bit of code is pretty much the same thing(modified to not take any input), only it's not in a separate file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255];

    char *str;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(fp) {
        while(fgets(buff, 255, fp)) {
            strcat(str, buff);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The second code bit, when I run it, produces a segmentation error.

Why are these different?

Comment: That's how [**undefined behaviour**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) works. You try to do `strcat` with `str`. Where did you allocate memory for `str`?

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand what you mean by allocating memory. I am new to C, coming from higher level languages like JavaScript so this terminology is new to me. Should I instead do `char str[]` or, at the strcat call, do `strcat(&str, buff)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocated memory for your pointer `str`. `strcat` however wants to access it's memory and thus fails (seg fault). You need to fix that in both functions. It **may** work sometimes, when `str` initially points to an actual address, but this would just be by coincident (it's still garbage data).

Comment: I am a little new to C. By allocating memory, what do you mean? When I see that, I think "declaring before defining".

Comment: Or do you mean by "not allocated" that I just declared a character pointer, nothing to point it to. And that instead of that, I should do `char str[]`?

Comment: Or, instead of `char str[]`, in the strcat call, I did `strcat(&str, buff)`

Comment: when you write `char *str`, there is no specific value in `str`. it's like declaring `int number`. what is the value of `number`? before you assign a value to it, it's value is random - it can be anything. same with `str`. you first have to **assign** a value to str. you can do this with `malloc` (dynamically), or, probably easier for you, with `char str[100]`. now `str` is an array that points to allocated memory (of size 100 bytes).